# How do I get this 'a' link, and 'input' button on the same line ? CSS

Tags: html, css

You can see them implemented here: http://jsfiddle.net/JvqAj/

If you notice, 'cancel my account' is higher than the button.

I would like both of them side-by-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `display` property to `inline`:

http://jsfiddle.net/durilai/2rNjh/

Answer (score 2):

Usually for things like this, I'd float the link:

```
a {
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `display: inline` for both the anchor `<a>` and the `button` and also readjust the left margin for button.